# QLPreviewController displays a PDF file, but the Activity View appears blank. No apps listed

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, qlpreviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an app that downloads a pdf file, which I then display using QLPreviewController. Tapping the "share" button in the top bar brings up an empty Activity View. It should contain "Print", "Open in iBooks", etc.

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzqrL.jpg

Everything works fine if I run my app through XCode, but if I create an AdHoc build, I get the empty menu shown in the screenshot. Below is my code:

```
- (void) DisplayFileWorker: (const wchar_t*) fileName
{
    iOSClient_AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
    previewController.delegate = appDelegate.serverViewController;
    previewController.dataSource = appDelegate.serverViewController;
    previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0;

    NSString* filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: (const void*)fileName
                                              length: wcslen(fileName) * sizeof(*fileName)
                                            encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];

    appDelegate.serverViewController.previewFile = filePath;

    [appDelegate.serverViewController presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];

    [previewController release]; 
}
```

I have tried copying the file elsewhere, changing permissions on the file, adding a pdf file to the resources, I always get the same blank menu. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the extension of the file and what does the filePath variable show in the debugger?